# Convert a list of hashIDs stored as string to a column of unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where in one column I have a list of hash values stored like strings:

```
'[d85235f50b3c019ad7c6291e3ca58093,03e0fb034f2cb3264234b9eae09b4287]' just to be clear.
```

the dataframe looks like

```
  1
0 [8a88e629c368001c18619c7cd66d3e96, 4b0709dd990a0904bbe6afec636c4213, c00a98ceb6fc7006d572486787e551cc, 0e72ae6851c40799ec14a41496d64406, 76475992f4207ee2b209a4867b42c372]
1 [3277ded8d1f105c84ad5e093f6e7795d]
2 [d85235f50b3c019ad7c6291e3ca58093, 03e0fb034f2cb3264234b9eae09b4287]
```

I'd like to create a list of unique hash id's present in this column.

What is the efficient way? 
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean? You want to flatten the column? Do you want to drop duplicates? Can you please be clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
See timing below for fastest option

You can embed the parsing and flattening in one comprehension

```
[y for x in df['1'].values.tolist() for y in x.strip('[]').split(', ')]

['8a88e629c368001c18619c7cd66d3e96',
 '4b0709dd990a0904bbe6afec636c4213',
 'c00a98ceb6fc7006d572486787e551cc',
 '0e72ae6851c40799ec14a41496d64406',
 '76475992f4207ee2b209a4867b42c372',
 '3277ded8d1f105c84ad5e093f6e7795d',
 'd85235f50b3c019ad7c6291e3ca58093',
 '03e0fb034f2cb3264234b9eae09b4287']
```

From there, you can use either `list(set())`, `pd.unique`, or `np.unique`

```
pd.unique([y for x in df['1'].values.tolist() for y in x.strip('[]').split(', ')])

array(['8a88e629c368001c18619c7cd66d3e96',
       '4b0709dd990a0904bbe6afec636c4213',
       'c00a98ceb6fc7006d572486787e551cc',
       '0e72ae6851c40799ec14a41496d64406',
       '76475992f4207ee2b209a4867b42c372',
       '3277ded8d1f105c84ad5e093f6e7795d',
       'd85235f50b3c019ad7c6291e3ca58093',
       '03e0fb034f2cb3264234b9eae09b4287'], dtype=object)
```

---

**Option 2**
For brevity, use `pd.Series.extractall`

```
list(set(df['1'].str.extractall('(\w+)')[0]))

['8a88e629c368001c18619c7cd66d3e96',
 '4b0709dd990a0904bbe6afec636c4213',
 'c00a98ceb6fc7006d572486787e551cc',
 '0e72ae6851c40799ec14a41496d64406',
 '76475992f4207ee2b209a4867b42c372',
 '3277ded8d1f105c84ad5e093f6e7795d',
 'd85235f50b3c019ad7c6291e3ca58093',
 '03e0fb034f2cb3264234b9eae09b4287']
```

---

**@jezrael's `list(set())` with my comprehension is fastest**

**Parse Timing**
I kept the same `list(set())` for purposes of comparing parsing and flattening.

```
%timeit list(set(np.concatenate(df['1'].apply(yaml.load).values).tolist()))
%timeit list(set([y for x in df['1'].values.tolist() for y in x.strip('[]').split(', ')]))
%timeit list(set(chain.from_iterable(df['1'].str.strip('[]').str.split(', '))))
%timeit list(set(df['1'].str.extractall('(\w+)')[0]))

1.01 ms ± 45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
6.42 µs ± 219 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
279 µs ± 8.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
941 µs ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

This takes my comprehension and uses various ways to make unique to compare those speeds

```
%timeit pd.unique([y for x in df['1'].values.tolist() for y in x.strip('[]').split(', ')])
%timeit np.unique([y for x in df['1'].values.tolist() for y in x.strip('[]').split(', ')])
%timeit list(set([y for x in df['1'].values.tolist() for y in x.strip('[]').split(', ')]))

57.8 µs ± 3.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
17.5 µs ± 552 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
6.18 µs ± 184 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Would you care to add in `yaml.load` too?

Comment: Thanks :) As always, one must pay the price for simplicity.

Comment: What about `list(set(chain.from_iterable([x.strip('[]').split(', ') for x in df['col'].values.tolist()])))` ? I am a nit confused what is the fastest ;(

Comment: And what is size of df? Are there duplicates? because OP data are unique :(

Comment: Simple timing, didn't adjust sizes.  Weird error when I run `timeit` on last suggestion.  I'll show something.

Comment: The timing I added isn't fair.  I need to figure out error.  Unfortunately, I have to run to store.  I removed it because it inaccurately reflects that your suggestion is slow when I suspect it is of similar speed.  When I put it through `timeit` I get `KeyError` on `' 1'`.  No idea why!!.  I swapped it with `df.iloc[:, 0]` which is a huge penalty when compared to `df['1']`.  That is why it isn't fair.  I'll try to figure out `timeit` bug later.

Answer (score 3):

You need [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) first and for flatenning `chain`:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
['col']

#convert strings to lists per rows
#change by your column name if necessary    
s = df['col'].str.strip('[]').str.split(', ')
print (s)
0    [8a88e629c368001c18619c7cd66d3e96, 4b0709dd990...
1                   [3277ded8d1f105c84ad5e093f6e7795d]
2    [d85235f50b3c019ad7c6291e3ca58093, 03e0fb034f2...
Name: col, dtype: object

#check first value
print (type(s.iat[0]))
<class 'list'>

#get unique values - for unique values use set
from  itertools import chain
L = list(set(chain.from_iterable(s)))

['76475992f4207ee2b209a4867b42c372', '3277ded8d1f105c84ad5e093f6e7795d',
 'd85235f50b3c019ad7c6291e3ca58093', '4b0709dd990a0904bbe6afec636c4213', 
 'c00a98ceb6fc7006d572486787e551cc', '03e0fb034f2cb3264234b9eae09b4287', 
 '8a88e629c368001c18619c7cd66d3e96', '0e72ae6851c40799ec14a41496d64406']
```

---

```
from  itertools import chain
s = [x.strip('[]').split(', ') for x in df['col'].values.tolist()]
L = list(set(chain.from_iterable(s)))
print (L)

['76475992f4207ee2b209a4867b42c372', '3277ded8d1f105c84ad5e093f6e7795d', 
 'd85235f50b3c019ad7c6291e3ca58093', '4b0709dd990a0904bbe6afec636c4213', 
 'c00a98ceb6fc7006d572486787e551cc', '03e0fb034f2cb3264234b9eae09b4287',
 '8a88e629c368001c18619c7cd66d3e96', '0e72ae6851c40799ec14a41496d64406']
```

Comment: See my answer on how to convert column of strings to column of lists...

Comment: If you're referring to the other question, then I don't think so. Because, if all you wanted to say was "don't use a dataframe, use a series", but kept the rest of the answer the same, that may as well have been added as a comment to my answer. And I would have improved it. Because besides that point they're both identical. But it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want to flatten your data. Convert it to a column of lists using `yaml.load`.

```
import yaml

df = df.applymap(yaml.load)
print(df)
                                            1
0  [8a88e629c368001c18619c7cd66d3e96, 4b0709dd990...
1                 [3277ded8d1f105c84ad5e093f6e7795d]
2  [d85235f50b3c019ad7c6291e3ca58093, 03e0fb034f2...
```

The easiest way would be to construct a new dataframe form the old one's values.

```
out = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.iloc[:, 0].values.tolist()))
print(out)

                                  0
0  8a88e629c368001c18619c7cd66d3e96
1  4b0709dd990a0904bbe6afec636c4213
2  c00a98ceb6fc7006d572486787e551cc
3  0e72ae6851c40799ec14a41496d64406
4  76475992f4207ee2b209a4867b42c372
5  3277ded8d1f105c84ad5e093f6e7795d
6  d85235f50b3c019ad7c6291e3ca58093
7  03e0fb034f2cb3264234b9eae09b4287
```

Comment: Added your method.